# How do I get a path with the correct (canonical) case in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that accepts a directory as an argument from the user.  I'd like to display the name of the directory path as it is displayed in Windows.  I.e.,

```
PS C:\SomeDirectory> cd .\anotherdirectory
PS C:\AnotherDirectory> . .\myscript.ps1 "c:\somedirectory"
C:\SomeDirectory
```

How do I retrieve "C:\SomeDirectory" when given "c:\somedirectory"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The accepted answer only gets the correct case of the file.  Parent paths are left with the case provided by the user.  Here's my solution.

```
$getPathNameSignature = @'
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern uint GetLongPathName(
    string shortPath, 
    StringBuilder sb, 
    int bufferSize);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
public static extern uint GetShortPathName(
   string longPath,
   StringBuilder shortPath,
   uint bufferSize);
'@
$getPathNameType = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $getPathNameSignature -Name GetPathNameType -UsingNamespace System.Text -PassThru


function Get-PathCanonicalCase
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        # Gets the real case of a path
        $Path
    )

    if( -not (Test-Path $Path) )
    {
        Write-Error "Path '$Path' doesn't exist."
        return
    }

    $shortBuffer = New-Object Text.StringBuilder ($Path.Length * 2)
    [void] $getPathNameType::GetShortPathName( $Path, $shortBuffer, $shortBuffer.Capacity )

    $longBuffer = New-Object Text.StringBuilder ($Path.Length * 2)
    [void] $getPathNameType::GetLongPathName( $shortBuffer.ToString(), $longBuffer, $longBuffer.Capacity )

    return $longBuffer.ToString()
}
```

I've integrated the above code into [Resolve-PathCase](http://get-carbon.org/help/Resolve-PathCase.html), part of the [Carbon](http://get-carbon.org) PowerShell module. *Disclaimer: I'm the owner/maintainer of Carbon.*

Comment: FYI `Get-PathCanonicalCase C:\ ` and `Get-PathCanonicalCase c:\ ` return different values. Also this func obviously doesn't work on network shares, would be nice if it had that functionality as well.

Comment: The GetLongPathName function doesn't seem to work: Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddType.AutoGeneratedTypes.GetPathNameType] does not contain a method named 'GetLongPathName'.

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
function Get-PathCanonicalCase {
    param($path)

    $newPath = (Resolve-Path $path).Path
    $parent = Split-Path $newPath

    if($parent) {
        $leaf = Split-Path $newPath -Leaf

        (Get-ChildItem $parent| Where-Object{$_.Name -eq $leaf}).FullName
    } else {
        (Get-PSDrive ($newPath -split ':')[0]).Root
    }
}
```

Comment: This hangs for the root directory, though. Try passing `c:\`.

Comment: Add a `IF ($path.root)` to verify the parameter has a root node

Comment: That was essentially the only way that I could do it but I didn't like it.

Comment: [System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories("c:\", "nameoffolder") is something to working on to have a single line call

Comment: Thank you!  I found another minor problem when passing '\', but changing `(Get-PSDrive ($Path -split ':')[0]).Root` to `(Get-PSDrive ($newPath -split ':')[0]).Root` fixed that.

Comment: It certainly does seem like there should be a way to do this without this much script though.  Still appreciate the script solution.

Comment: @Glenn - Agreed it does seem long; Christian's comment has a short solution for directories. I updated my answer with the `$newPath` change you mentioned.

Comment: By the way, `Resolve-Path` *could* perhaps work in a similar manner: `function s($path){Resolve-Path ($path -replace '[^\\/][\\/]?$','?')|?{$_.Path -ieq $path -replace '[\\/]$'}|select -exp Path}` – this doesn't work for drive roots initially, though, so needs a bit work. Just thought I'd throw this in here :)

Answer (score 3):

I found a different and simpler approach using PowerShell wild cards.

```
 $canonicalCasePath = Get-ChildItem -Path $wrongCasingPath.Replace("\","\*") | Where FullName -IEQ $wrongCasingPath | Select -ExpandProperty FullName
```

- The first part of the pipe replaces all backslashes in the path by
  backslash and asterisk **\** → **\*** and return all matching files
- The where part makes sure that only the desired file is returned and
  not any other potential match. IEQ is case insesitive equal
- The last select part extracts canonical case path
  of the file

Comment: This actually works and appears to be bulletproof thanks to the exact-matching Where clause. I was concerned that it might return e.g. "C:\123Documents" when searching "c:\documents" but the Where clause takes care of it. This is an approach that I can easily understand, even if it is not guaranteed to be the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

Using Christian's `GetDirectories` suggestion, here's another solution that's not quite as involved:

```
function Get-PathCanonicalCase
{
    param( $path )

    $newPath = (Resolve-Path $path).Path
    $root = [System.IO.Path]::GetPathRoot( $newPath )
    if ( $newPath -ne $root ) # Handle case where changing to root directory
        { $newPath = [System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories( $root, $newPath.Substring( $root.Length ) )[ 0 ] }
    $newPath
}
```

EDIT:  Thanks for all the help.

Btw, all I wanted this for was to use in a little utility script overriding the default cd alias, allowing me to specify some 'root' directories that are searched if the path doesn't exist relative to the current directory.  I.e., it allows me to `cd Documents`, `cd trunk`, `cd Release-10.4` regardless of my current location.  And it annoyed me to have the prompt in the case that I entered it, instead of its actual case.

```
# Usage: 
# Set up in $profile - define the functions and reassign 'cd'.  Example:
# -----
#  . .\Set-LocationEx.ps1 "c:\dev\Code", "c:\dev\Code\releases", "$HOME" -Verbose
# if (test-path alias:cd) { remove-item alias:cd > $null }
# Set-Alias cd Set-LocationEx
# -----

param( [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string[]]$roots )

Set-StrictMode -Version Latest

Write-Verbose "Set-LocationEx roots: $(Join-String -Strings $roots -Separator ', ')"

function Set-LocationEx
{
    param( [Parameter( Mandatory="true" )]$path )

    process
    { 
        $verbose = ( $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.BoundParameters.ContainsKey( "Verbose" ) -and $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.BoundParameters[ "Verbose" ].IsPresent )
        if ( $verbose )
            { Write-Verbose( "$(Join-String -Strings $roots -Separator ', ')" ) }
        if ( !( Test-Path $path ) ) 
        {
            foreach ( $p in $roots )
            { 
                $newPath = Join-Path $p $path
                if ( $verbose ) { Write-Verbose "Looking for $newPath" }
                if ( Test-Path $newPath ) 
                { 
                    $newPath = Get-PathCanonicalCase( $newPath )
                    if ( $verbose ) { Write-Verbose "Found $newPath" }
                    Push-Location $newPath
                    return
                } 
            }
        }
        if ( Test-Path $path )
            { $path = Get-PathCanonicalCase( $path ) }
        Push-Location $path
    }
}

function Get-LocationExRoots
{
    process
    {
        Write-Output (Join-String -Strings $roots -NewLine)
    }
}

function Get-PathCanonicalCase
{
    param( $path )

    $newPath = (Resolve-Path $path).Path
    $root = [System.IO.Path]::GetPathRoot( $newPath )
    if ( $newPath -ne $root ) # Handle root directory
        { $newPath = [System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories( $root, $newPath.Substring( $root.Length ) )[ 0 ] }
    $newPath
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan of recursive functions, so I adapted [honzajscz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502042)'s answer[<sup>1</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42213654) into a function that doesn't trip over wildcard characters and will even work with relative paths.

---

### Solution <sub><sup>*works on both PowerShell 5.1  &  7.4  !!*</sup></sub>

`````
function Get-CanonicalPath {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [Alias('PSPath')]
    $Path
  )
  $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
  $pathEscape = {
    $str = $args[0].Replace('`','````')
    $str = [WildcardPattern]::Escape($str)
    return [WildcardPattern]::Escape($str)
  }
  $normalizeSlashes = {
    return $args[0].Replace('\','/').TrimEnd('/')
  }
  $wildcardPath = {
    $path = & $normalizeSlashes $args[0]
    $root = & $normalizeSlashes ([IO.Path]::GetPathRoot($path))
    $pattern = & $pathEscape $path.Substring($root.Length + 1)
    $pattern = $pattern.Replace('/','*/')
    return '{0}*' -f (Join-Path $root $pattern)
  }
  $rPath = $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath("$Path")
  $PARAM = @{
    Path       =  & $wildcardPath $rPath
    Directory  =  $rPath[-1] -in '/','\'
  }
  @(Get-ChildItem @PARAM) -as 'string[]' -eq $rPath.TrimEnd('/\')
}
`````

### How It Works

Escaping paths in Get-ChildItem is pretty annoying, particularly because you need to double-escape them if you're using full paths. So, for consistency, `GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath` is used to create a full path string.

`$wildcardPath` is a function variable that first calls the `$normalizeSlashes` function variable on the path to change backslashes to forward-slashes (it's simpler that way); then, it uses `[IO.Path]::GetPathRoot` to define the `$root` variable. Everything in the path except for the root drive is passed to the `$pathEscape` variable, which (as previously mentioned) double-escapes wildcard characters. An asterisk is placed before every forward-slash not part of the root, and finally it's returned with an additional asterisk at the end.

`Get-ChildItem`'s parameters are defined, and I made it so if the path you give it ends in a slash, it'll match only directores (via `$rPath[-1] -in '/','\'`). The output of `Get-ChildItem` is forced to be an object array (for some reason this is necessary for the following conversion), then it's casted as a string array, and finally, we rely on the way comparison operators and collections interact to case-insensitively compare the output to the original path (with trailing slashes removed).

### Demonstration

```
$demoPath = New-Item 'C:\TempTestDir_SafeToDelete\foo`[BAR]' -Type File -Force -vb

$rngCase = -join ($demoPath -split '').ForEach{ ($_.ToLower(),$_.ToUpper())[(Get-Random 2)] }

Write-Host ('{0}Using the string "{1}" to derive the path "{2}"{0}' -f "`n", $rngCase, $demoPath)

Get-CanonicalPath $rngCase

Write-Host ('{0}Demonstration concluded, removing "{1}"{0}' -f "`n", $demoPath.Directory)

Remove-Item -LiteralPath $demoPath,$demoPath.Directory -vb
```

### Example Output

```
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Create Directory" on target "Destination: C:\TempTestDir_SafeToDelete".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Create File" on target "Destination: C:\TempTestDir_SafeToDelete\foo`[BAR]".

Using the string "c:\TeMPtestdiR_sAfeTODElEte\foO`[bAR]" for the path "C:\TempTestDir_SafeToDelete\foo`[BAR]"

C:\TempTestDir_SafeToDelete\foo`[BAR]

Demonstration concluded, removing "C:\TempTestDir_SafeToDelete"

VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\TempTestDir_SafeToDelete\foo`[BAR]".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "C:\TempTestDir_SafeToDelete".
```

---